# Bottle neck issue while using Q.all()

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, q

I am new to nodeJS and promises and using Q promise library. I am facing a situation where I need to resolve array of promises and then use the result. I have used Q.all([arrayOfPromise]) to resolve all promises. Here each promise is doing DB operation so number of active DB connections are crossing the size of connection pool and getting error.

I have gone through Q library documentation - https://github.com/kriskowal/q
But could not find any solution.

```
const process = () => {
    const arrayOfIds = [id1, id2, id3, id4 .... idn] 
        // getById is fetching data from DB asynchronously 
    const arrayOfPromises = arrayOfIds.map(id => getById(id))

    return Q.all([arrayOfPromises])
      .then(resultArray => {
        // utilization of result array
      })
}
```

Can anyone suggest better approach to do same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean, in sql it's just a `SELECT * WHERE id IN ('id1', 'id2', ...)`, why even use many `getById` in the first place?

Comment: You basically are trying to synchronize your asynchronous code... Maybe use some sort of loop, since you are limited in your db connections.

Comment: Maybe create a new Promise and resolve it in an a recursive loop function with the arrayOfPromises.

Answer (score 1):

`Q` is just a util, don't see why they would handle DB specific problem.

One thing you can do is to design some queue-like mechanism to control the total size of concurrent DB ops allowed. In order word, control the size of your `arrayOfPromise`.

I don't know the nature of your problem, but why don't you get data in one batched query instead of many `getById`?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by other users, a better solution to your problem will be to use `WHERE id IN ( .. )` type of query.

The problem in your case is concurrency of operations. N operations are being executed parallely, which is causing the issue. In worst case, they may even cause unexpected crashes or increased resource usage for your NodeJS process.

`Q` or native `Promise` doesn't have a method to control concurrency of execution. If you absolutely have to use Promise.all, I would suggest to use `Bluebird.map` ([Link](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)).

```
const process = () => {
    const arrayOfIds = [id1, id2, id3, id4 .... idn] 

    return Bluebird.map(arrayOfIds, 
        (id) => getById(id),
        { concurrency: 5 } // Default +Inifinity
    )
      .then(resultArray => {
        // utilization of result array
      })
}
```

Of course, you'll have to ensure that promise returned by `getById` is Bluebird compatible (not sure about Q promise, but native Promise is)